# Generating thumbnail using generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes freezes the screen untill image gets generated in iOS 8

Tags: ios8

i am trying to generate thumbnails from http url using generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes. which was perfectly working in ios 7.1. but after i have upgraded to iOS 8, this isn't working in an asynchronous way.screen freezes until image gets generated.

Here is the code which i am trying to use:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoContentIDFullPath] options:nil];

AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;

CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }
    // TODO Do something with the image
    self.imageview.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:im];;

};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(128, 128);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: did you find a solution? facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; <--

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
        if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ <--
            // TODO Do something with the image
            weakSelf.imageview.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:im]; <--
        });

    };
```